# pouchdb - secure replication with remote LevelDB

Tags: ssl, replication, pouchdb

I am keen on using PouchDB in browser memory for an Angular application. This PouchDB will replicate *from* a remote LevelDB database that is fed key-value pairs from an algorithm. So, on the remote end, I would install [PouchDB-Server](https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html). On the local end, I would do the following (as described [here](https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html)) on a `node` prompt.

```
var localDB = new PouchDB('mylocaldb')
var remoteDB = new PouchDB('https://remote-ip-address:5984/myremotedb')
localDB.sync(remoteDB, {
  live: true
}).on('change', function (change) {
  // yo, something changed!
}).on('error', function (err) {
  // yo, we got an error! (maybe the user went offline?)
});
```

How do we start a PouchDB instance that supports TLS for live replication as described in the snippet above?
How do I start a PouchDB instance that supports TLS for live replication?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you intend to connect to a CouchDB server with PouchDB through `HTTPS`. Therefore, the following answer actually **doesn't answer** your question.

---

I created a `server.js` file like below to communicate with my CouchDB through `HTTPS`. Please note that the `SSL` certificate is (in my case) self-signed, and also CouchDB listens by default on port `6984` in the case of `TLS`:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"; // Ignore rejection, becasue CouchDB SSL certificate is self-signed

//import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb')
const db = new PouchDB('https://admin:****@192.168.1.106:6984/reproduce')

db.allDocs({
    include_docs: true,
    attachments: false
}).then(function (result) {
    // handle result
    console.log(result)
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I'm running the above file with `$ node server.js` and I'm getting the expected results:

```
$ node server.js 
{ total_rows: 3,
  offset: 0,
  rows: 
   [ { id: '5d6590d3-41c7-4011-be5d-b21f80079ae5',
       key: '5d6590d3-41c7-4011-be5d-b21f80079ae5',
       value: [Object],
       doc: [Object] },
     { id: 'ec6a36d1-952e-4d86-9865-3587c6079fb5',
       key: 'ec6a36d1-952e-4d86-9865-3587c6079fb5',
       value: [Object],
       doc: [Object] },
     { id: 'f508e7aa-b4dc-42fc-96be-b7c1ffa54172',
       key: 'f508e7aa-b4dc-42fc-96be-b7c1ffa54172',
       value: [Object],
       doc: [Object] } ] }
```

---

I created the above code with NodeJS on server-side. However, if you want to communicate with CouchDB through `HTTPS` inside the browser, i.e. on client-side, you have to [enable CORS on CouchDB](https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb#add-cors-to-couchdb-).

Comment: I want to run PouchDB-Server that uses LevelDB (default) as the underlying storage engine. And, I am not clear on how to start PouchDB-Server with TLS. Can you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

So after some more searching, it is clear from [this topic](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server/issues/169), HTTPS is not supported for PocuhDB-Server.